# How to make use of xarray's sparse functionality when combining differently sized dask arrays?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, dask, python-xarray

As xarray rolls out more and more sparse array functionality, I am wondering how to achieve the following:

I have a (actually lazy, not loaded) dask array arr_a of size let's say 2x1000
and a dask array arr_b of size 2x10:

```
from dask import array as da
import numpy as np

arr_a = da.from_array(np.random.rand(2, 1000))
arr_b = da.from_array(np.random.rand(2, 10))
```

I create now two xarray DataArrays with "same" but differently sampled time axis:

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

time1 = pd.timedelta_range(0, periods=1000, freq="ms")/pd.offsets.Second(1)
time2 = pd.timedelta_range(0, periods=10, freq="100ms")/pd.offsets.Second(1)

xr1 = xr.DataArray(arr_a , dims=["cycle", "time"], coords={"time": time1, "cycle": [1,2]}).rename("ch1")
xr2 = xr.DataArray(arr_b , dims=["cycle", "time"], coords={"time": time2, "cycle": [1,2]}).rename("ch2")

xr_data = xr.combine_by_coords([xr1.to_dataset(), xr2.to_dataset()])
```

After combining/mergin both DataArrays into a Dataset, the second variable xr2 is sparse and filled with NaNs. That is actually great, but each NaN needs memory space.
I have to find a way, these NaN items do not need memory.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

A very big thanks to the xarray and dask team for your amazing work!

Comment: Sorry for the wrong inital reproduction code. Aboves code works with newest xarray (0.15) and newest dask (2.10.1) modules

Answer (score 3):

Either:

```py
arr_a = arr_a.map_blocks(sparse.COO)
arr_b = arr_b.map_blocks(sparse.COO)
```

Or:

```py
xr1 = xarray.apply_ufunc(sparse.COO, xr1, dask="parallelized", output_dtypes=[xr1.dtype])
xr2 = xarray.apply_ufunc(sparse.COO, xr2, dask="parallelized", output_dtypes=[xr1.dtype])
```

which in this case are equivalent.

*after* converting your data to sparse, you can align and merge.

Comment: Unfortunately, after merging/aligning the sparse data, the resulting xarray appears to be non-sparse again.
Nevertheless, after ```xarray.apply_ufunc(sparse.COO, ...)``` again on the resulting merged/aligned xarray, the new xarray again is very big.
When the data inside dask origins from a lazy defined hdf5 file, pickling that aligned xarray, it obviously holds data inside the pickle and not the lazy definition graph only.
I guess that is a dask issue?!

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. You literally *cannot* accidentally make a sparse array eager again; sparse will crash unless you explicitly set an environment variable for it (see sparse documentation).

sparse.COO by default has 0 as the fill value. xarray will put NaN as the fill value when aligning. Hence you need to invoke sparse.COO with fill value = NaN.

Pickling a lazily loaded NetCDF file will eagerly load it into the pickle, as designed. The result will be all the relevant chunks of the dataset plus the lazy dask directives to convert it to your final array.

Comment: I try to make a better minimal example, making my issue better reproducible. I'll post it here and on github. Thank you for trying helping me out here!